# Laravel 4: Select row if a relation exists by querying relation

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to query a products table, and want it to return a collection if a relation exists.

**Iteration 1** below queries **all** rows in the products table, and lazy loads the metals table if `$name` matches. This is wrong.

My Route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{api}/v1'), function()
{
    Route::controller('products', 'Api\V1\ProductController');
});
```

My Controller:

```
public function getFilter($metal = null) {
    $products = $this->product;
    if ($metal) {
        $products->with('metal', function($query, $metal) {
            $query->where('name', $metal);
        });
    }
    return Response::api($products->get());
}
```

I want **only** `$products` to display if `metal.name = $metal`. e.g. something like:

```
$this->products->where('metal.name', $metal)->get;
```

**Solution using part of Glad To Help's answer:**

This provides an alternative approach 2, without the need for joins.

http://paste.laravel.com/WC4

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading), see *Eager Load Constraints*. Try to pass a array to the *with* function instead: `$products->with(array('metal' => function($query) use ($metal)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with one swipe in Eloquent yet.

BUT, there is  a way by using the inverse relation, like this:

```
public function getFilter($metal = null)
{
    // filter the metals first
    $metals = Metal::with('products')->where('name', '=' , $metal)->get();
    $products = array();
    foreach($metals as $metal)
    {
           // collect the products from the filtered metals
           $products = array_merge($products, $metal->products->toArray() );
    }
    return $products;
}
```

If this is not elegant solution for you, you will either have to use Fluent to construct the query and join the products x metals table manually or pre-join them by overriding the newQuery() method.

1) alternative approach one.

```
public function getFilter($metal = null) {
    return DB::table('products')->join('metal', 'products.id', '=' , 'metal.product_id')
                         ->where('metal.name', $name)
                         ->select(array('products.*'));
}
```

2) alternative approach two

```
class Product extends Eloquent{

public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true){
        return parent::newQuery()->join('metal','id','=','metal.product_id');
    }

}
```