# A shopping cart ORM check in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my table structure

**users**

```
id
username
password
```

**orders**

```
id
user_id
```

**order_details**

```
id
product_id
order_id
```

And the relationship is all set

User.php

```
function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany('Order');
}
```

Order.php

```
function details() {
    return $this->hasMany('OrderDetail');
}
```

OrderDetail.php

I got user id and product id, I want to check if the user bought this product

`User::find($userId)->orders()->details()->where('product_id', $productId)->count()` will be wrong, because orders return more than one data, how to do the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with one swipe with Eloquent yet. But you can easily write a function like this to do the check:

```
public function hasBoughtProduct($product_id, $user_id)
{

$orders = Orders::with('details')->where('user_id','=',$user_id)->get();

foreach($orders as $order)
{
    $details = $order->details()->where('product_id', '=', $product_id)->count();
    if($details > 0)
    {
          return TRUE;
    }    
}
return FALSE;
}
```

If this is not efficient enough for your needs, you might consider using Fluent to write the query or override the newQuery() method where you will pre-join the tables. If this suits you more, you can refer to this answer for more details on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19183957/385402