# How to bind model to query string parameter in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I understand that you can bind Models to route parameters in Laravel, but is there a way they can be bound to optional query string parameters.

For example, given a URL of:

```
http://myapi.example.com/products?category_id=345
```

That uses a route of:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

Is there a way to bind our optional query string parameter `category_id` to our Category model, so that it can be automatically injected into the ProductController?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, I don't think that is possible with a resource route because it automatically maps some RESTful routes to a given resource (as per the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)). If you want a route with optional parameters, you will have to use some of the other options for writing routes in Laravel and make sure you place it before declaring the resource controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but not as your question asks.

> Is there a way to bind our optional query string parameter category_id
>   to our Category model, so that it can be automatically injected into
>   the ProductController?

You bind the query string parameter to the product model, not the category model.

Below is a quick and dirty method of sending filtered data to the view based on query string input. This filters the category relation.

There may be syntax errors as I just quickly knocked an answer out - but the concept works.

**ProductController**

```
class ProductController extends BaseController
{
    protected $productModel;
    function __construct(Product $productModel)
    {
        $this->$productModel = $productModel;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $products = $this->productModel
            ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id');
            ->select(// select your columns)

        $filterCategory = Input::get('category_id');

        if ($filterCategory)
        {
            ->where('category_id', '=', $filterCategory)
        } 

        $data = $products->get();

        return View::make( 'shop.product.index')->with($data);
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to abstract this code away from the controller and override the newQuery method of the model.

It was in fact Glad to Help's answer in one of my similar questions who introduced me to the newQuery method. [Laravel 4: Select row if a relation exists by querying relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177141/laravel-4-select-row-if-a-relation-exists-by-querying-relation)